# psycopg2 on OSX not pip installing

Tags: python, postgresql, macos, homebrew, psycopg2

There are a few problems asked about installing psycopg2 on OSX.

Like:

- [Error with library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15908783/1736679)
- [Error with compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59913893/1736679)
- [Import error with library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14863723/1736679)
- [Missing pg_conf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10132274/1736679)

After sorting out pg_conf still stuck with `library not found for -lssl`

On:

- OSX
- M1 Mac
- Python 3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68792766/1736679), was able to make it work without needing the whole of postgres installed, by using `brew`.

Sadly zlib or openssl are not explained in the install [requirements for psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html)

Verified with:

- OSX: Monterey 12.4
- Python: 3.9.13
- pip: 22.1.2
- psycopg2: 2.8.5

Steps:

- Install libpq: `brew install libpq`
- Add to path, so pg_conf is found, eg:

  ```bash
  export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH
  ```
- Install openssl: `brew install openssl`
- Add to library paths, eg:

  ```bash
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"
  ```
- `pip install psycopg2==2.8.5`